# Why can Compute Shaders be used to enhance performance?

Tags: performance, opengl, shader, rendering, compute-shader

I'm currently researching compute shaders. It is said, that under certain circumstances compute shaders can produce vastly *faster* rendering results than the standard (say OpenGL) hardware pipeline.

I understand that it has something to do with work groups and work group invocations and as such with thread utilization and parallel computation.

But I still haven't come across a good source that explains the parallels and differences between the standard rendering pipeline and compute pipeline in terms of actual performance.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: AFAIK, the standard OpenGL hardware pipeline is now completely obsolete and it should either use generic default shaders internally or an unoptimized obsolete path only main to be used for backward compatibility. It is like GPU VESA mode (eg. via BIOS extensions): it is very slow on modern GPUs while the "accelerated" vendor-specific modes are far much faster nowadays. Why would GPU vendors optimize applications using obsolete features? It is all about cost. Besides, your question is a too vague to be answered objectively. Please add a precise example.

Comment: Hey, my research topic is "Point Cloud Rasterization using Compute Shaders". It is said that this method of rendering can achieve up to 10x better (meaning faster) performances. Can you maybe give me just an intuition as to what compute shaders could have to do with rendering speed?

Comment: "*Point Cloud Rasterization using Compute Shaders*" That is a very specific circumstance. You should probably put that into your question. Also, there's **no need** for **all the** bold face; your post is not so long that we can't pick out the **important** parts.

Comment: Shaders are a tool. It is not shared that will make things faster. It is the algorithms / computing methods. The old standard OpenGL pipeline is not flexible enough for a lot of problem. Shaders enable developers to write algorithms that *better fit* to the GPU hardware computing units than the old pipeline. The lack of flexibility force developers to do indirect operations that are often be more expensive. IDK for the "Point Cloud Rasterization" (probably still a bit too vague).

Comment: In the broadest sense: with the standard pipelines, you automatically inherit certain algorithms which may not be very good for your use case. With compute shaders, you can build from the ground up for the most part.

Comment: The standard rendering pipeline is going to run the vertex shader, run a rasterization step then run the fragment shader on certain-sized blocks of pixels, more-or-less, and it's optimized for lots of adjacent triangles. It's quite conceivable that there are algorithms that do the processing faster on certain kinds of data. With a point cloud, you know you will be randomly accessing the picture, so running shaders on blocks of pixels per point is a waste of resources.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers and tips. How I understand all your answers, the standard pipeline could waste a lot of "potential" or computation power by going through unnecessary stages/shaders duo to lack of flexibility. Many Threads may be left unused or used for the wrong things. In this sense, when talking about gl_point primitives. What exactly does the rasterizer do since it doesn't really have to rasterize faces but just single fragments? Maybe we are wasting unnecessary time by "invoking" (can you say that?) a standard opengl rasterizer...?